# Rspec Retry Gem - How to configure for Netread::Timeout errors only?

Tags: ruby, rspec, automation

Is there a way to configure [the rspec-retry gem](https://github.com/NoRedInk/rspec-retry) to only perform retries on `Netread::Timeout` errors?

Answer (score -1):

As per [the README](https://github.com/NoRedInk/rspec-retry#configuration), you can put it in the RSpec configuration:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.exceptions_to_retry [Netread::Timeout]
end
```

---

On another note though, I think this gem is flawed in its conception. You shouldn't retry flaky tests, you should fix them.

If you do some networking in your specs, simply use [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr). It will make them not only reliable, but way faster as well.

Comment: [It doesn't work for `Net::ReadTimeout`](https://github.com/NoRedInk/rspec-retry/issues/100). I'm also using VCR with no external requests and I still run into Net::ReadTimeout sometimes.